# Pointers and assignment in a sub-function

Tags: c, struct

I have a small program that creates a semver `struct` with some variables in it:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned major;
    unsigned minor;
    unsigned patch;
    char * note;
    char * tag;
} semver;
```

Then, I would like to create a function which creates a semver `struct` and returns it to the caller. Basically, a Factory.

That factory would call an initialize function to set the default values of the semver `struct`:

```
void init_semver(semver * s) {
    s->major = 0;
    s->minor = 0;
    s->patch = 0;

    s->note = "alpha";

    generate_semver(s->tag, s);
}
```

And on top of that, I would like a function to generate a string of the complete semver tag.

```
void generate_semver(char * tag, semver * s) {
    sprintf( tag, "v%d.%d.%d-%s",
        s->major, s->minor, s->patch, s->note);
}
```

My problem appears to lie in this function. I have tried returning a string, but have heard that `malloc`ing some space is bad unless you explicitly `free` it later ;) In order to avoid this problem, I decided to try to pass a string to the function to have it be changed within the function with no return value. I'm trying to loosely follow something like DI practices, even though I'd really like to separate the concerns of these functions and have the `generate_semver` function return a string that I can use like so:

```
char * generate_semver(semver * s) {
    char * full_semver;
    sprintf( full_semver, "v%d.%d.%d-%s",
        s->major, s->minor, s->patch, s->note);
    return full_semver; // I know this won't work because it is defined in the local stack and not outside.
}

semver->tag = generate_semver(semver);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to either pass a valid char buffer into `generate_semver` to be filled, or dynamically allocate memory to contain the message and return a pointer to it which the caller must eventually free. You could also have the `semver` structure def have a large enough buffer itself rather than dealing with just pointers.As-written you're invoking undefined behavior because `full_server` is indeterminate. You have to decide which way you want to swing, and what you currently have isn't it.

Comment: Edit: you do not need to apologize for poor command of the C language - after all, nearly all questions on this site come from people who are learning something. Good question!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with factory functions in C, but it's also common to have corresponding pairs of `create` and `destroy` functions. So I'd suggest you add a `destroy_semver()` function, and then use `malloc` inside your factory.

Comment: I concur. this question has all it needs. A runnable example really isn't needed, as you have literally everything here needed, including your assessment and alternate considerations. nice post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem appears to lie in this function. I have tried returning a string, but have heard that mallocing some space is bad unless you explicitly free it later.

Explicitly freeing dynamically allocated memory is required to avoid memory leaks. However, it is not necessarily a task that the end users need to perform directly: an API often provides a function to deal with this.

In your case, you should provide a `deinit_semver` function that does the clean up of memory that `init_semver` has allocated dynamically. These two functions behave in a way that is similar to constructor and destructor; `init_semver` is *not* a factory function, because it expects the `semver` `struct` to be allocated, rather than allocating it internally.

Here is one way of doing it:

```
void init_semver(semver * s, int major, int minor, int pathc, const char * note) {
    s->major = major;
    s->minor = minor;
    s->patch = pathc;

    size_t len = strlen(note);
    s->note = malloc(len+1);
    strcpy(s->note, note);
    s->tag = malloc(40 + len);
    sprintf(s->tag, "v%d.%d.%d-%s", major, minor, patch, note);
}
void deinit_semver(semver *s) {
    free(s->note);
    free(s->tag);
}
```

Note the changes above: rather than using fixed values for the components of `struct` `semver`, this code takes the values as parameters. In addition, the code copies the `note` into a dynamically allocated buffer, rather than pointing to it directly.

The `deinit` function does the clean-up by `free`-ing both fields that were allocated dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it common practice in C to have the user call the de-initialize functions themselves? I know construct/destruct functions are common practice in many languages, but it's always a pain to remember to de-initialize everything after use. Is there a pattern that avoids this?

Comment: @Adam yes, that's common practice. Unfortunately, you cannot avoid it in C - it's the price you have to pay for the very fine-grained control you get over memory management.

Comment: @Adam Unfortunately, C does not provide a way to call functions automatically. C++ does, and builds a very powerful RAII idiom around it, but that is an entirely different language.

Comment: Thank you for the info pertaining to the best practices, also.

Answer (score 1):

A `char *` on its own is just a pointer to memory. To accomplish what you want you will either need to instead use a fixed size field, i.e. `char[33]`, or you can dynamically allocate the memory as needed.

As it is, your `generate_semver` function is attempting to print to an unknown address. Let's look at one solution.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned major;
    unsigned minor;
    unsigned patch;
    char     note[32];
    char     tag[32];
} semver;
```

Now, in your `init_semver` function, the line previously `s->note = "alpha";` will become a string copy, as arrays are not a valid lvalue.

```
strncpy(s->note, "alpha", 31);
s->note[31] = '\0';
```

`strncpy` will copy a string from the second parameter to the first up to the number of bytes in the third parameter. The second line ensures that a trailing null terminator is in place.

Similarly, in the `generate_semver` function, it would directly work in the buffer:

```
void generate_semver(semver * s) {
    snprintf( s->tag, 32, "v%d.%d.%d-%s",
        s->major, s->minor, s->patch, s->note);
}
```

This will directly print to the array in the structure, with a maximum character limit. `snprintf` does append a trailing null terminator (unlike `strncpy`), so we don't need to worry about adding it ourselves.

Comment: If I could accept your answer as a solution also, I would. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mention having to free allocated memory, and then say: "In order to avoid this problem". Well, it's not so much a problem, but rather a *necessity* of the C language. It's common to have functions that allocate memory, and require the caller to free it again.

The idiomatic way is to have a pair of "create" and "destroy" functions. So I'd suggest doing it like this:

```
// Your factory function
semver* create_semver() {
    semver* instance = malloc(sizeof(*instance));
    init_semver(instance); // will also allocate instance->tag and ->note
    return instance;
}

// Your destruction function
void free_semver(semver* s) {
    free(semver->tag);
    free(semver->note);
    free(semver);
}
```

Comment: You're right, it's not a problem. I misspoke. It's just something I'm trying to avoid because of my bias from knowing other languages where you don't have to do it. I'll get over that bias very quickly, though.